# How to view record from DB with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I try to view my record from DB by Code Igniter following the tutorial on this  [site](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/codeigniter-tutorials/display-records-from-database-using-php-codeigniter) but it show the error message

what can I try to make it identified?

Belows is view "view_inlist.php" code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Number</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Unit</strong></td>  
            <td><strong>Date</strong></td> 
        </tr> 
        <?php foreach($LIST as $list)
        {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$list->ID;?></td>
            <td><?=$list->Name;?></td>
            <td><?=$list->Letter_Number;?></td>
            <td><?=$list->Letter_Type;?></td>
            <td><?=$list->Unit;?></td>
            <td><?=$list->Date;?></td>
        </tr>     
        <?php }?>
    </table>
```

Here is controller "Main.php"

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Main extends CI_Controller {
      public function check_inList() {
          $this->load->model('login');
          $query = $this->login->check_inlist();
          $data['LIST'] = null;
          if($query){
             $data['LIST'] =  $query;
          }
          $this->load->view('form/view_inlist', $data);
      }        
    }
```

Here is Model "login.php"

```
function check_inlist(){                                                 
   $this->db->select("ID,Name,Letter_Number,Letter_Type,Unit,Date");
   $this->db->from('in_list');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you getting error on check_inList() action?

Comment: It doesn't identify the $LIST in view. I don't know how it is communicate each other. @B.Desai

Comment: I am asking you "When will you get this error?" give your url example

Comment: print the value of $query in controller ie, print_r($query); exit;

Comment: I think you forgot to load model in controller Main.php. To load the model in controller simply write $this->load->model('login');

Comment: Into your controller instead of `$data['LIST'] = null;` write this `$data['LIST'] = array();` then check

Comment: @B.Desai my code is error while loading view. This view load the data from database to display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

    in controller

<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Main extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('login');
  }

      public function check_inList() {
          $data['all_list'] = $this->login->check_inlist();

          $this->load->view('form/view_inlist', $data);
      }


    }





in model 

<?php

class Login extends CI_Model {


 function check_inlist(){                                                 
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('in_list');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
}

}

in view page 


       <?php foreach($all_list as $list) {?>

         <tr>       

            <td><?php echo $list->ID;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $list->Name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $list->Letter_Number;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $list->Letter_Type;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $list->Unit;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $list->Date;?></td>
        </tr> 
    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first check your database structure because in model you fetch  **EMAIL** column

`$this->db->select("ID,Name,Letter_Number,Letter_Type,Unit,EMAIL");`

And you print Date column `<td><?=$list->Date;?></td>` in view

**1.Controller**
Main.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Main extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('login');
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }


  public function check_inList() {
      $query = $this->login->check_inlist();
      $data['LIST'] = null;
      if($query){

         $data['LIST'] =  $query;
      }
      $this->load->view('view_inlist', $data);
  }        
}
?>
```

**2)Views** 
view_inlist.php

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Number</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unit</strong></td>  
        <td><strong>Date</strong></td> 
    </tr> 
    <?php foreach($LIST as $list)
    {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$list->ID;?></td>
        <td><?=$list->Name;?></td>
        <td><?=$list->Letter_Number;?></td>
        <td><?=$list->Letter_Type;?></td>
        <td><?=$list->Unit;?></td>
        <td><?=$list->EMAIL;?></td>
    </tr>     
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

**3.Model** Login.php

```
    <?php

    class Login extends CI_Model {
    function HomeModel(){
    parent::Model();
    }

    function check_inlist(){                                                 
    $this->db->select("ID,Name,Letter_Number,Letter_Type,Unit,EMAIL");
    $this->db->from('in_list');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It is not possible.i tried all code and got result sucessfully

Comment: I also wonder with my code, Could you command all your code on this, then I will check it step by step to find my mistake

Comment: @PhearumChheang i put

Comment: @PhearumChheang check table structure which you are use in model

Comment: Is there any problem because of php version?

Comment: I found the solution and it works. but another error also happen. If I input data and submit successfully, it will link to view the other page that list all item. But cannot show and will error. If I load that page without from insert form data, it shows all item from database.